# Open-source audio visualization?

Tags: open-source, video, audio

Is there some open-source (or simply free) solution to add audio visualization (frequency bands/fourier viz/generic scripting) to music in order to produce a simple music video from mp3?

Linux/Windows would be preferable. Since there are quite a few JNI bindings for OpenGL/video stuff in Java, I'm thinking about writing something in Java and using OpenGL shaders.

Comment: Do you have an OS preference?

Comment: OOhhh... I could use this too, esp. if I could define what visualizations to use (MildDrop, etc).  I have access to a planetarium and projector system :)  Preferrably on Linux.  Not to hijack the question or anything....

Comment: VLC has visualizations built in, though my personal problem with that is that I doubt that you can use those to produce videos - unless you are doing screen capturing using a 2nd program. But it should work with live viz.